# Resolving paths after compile in Typescript

Tags: typescript

Some background.
I use gulp to setup a stream that compiles my typescript code and outputs it into specified folders named in pairs. So `src` will be output to `lib`. `test_src` to `test` and so on.

My problem is that to write test code for my typescript modules in typescript i need to import them through the original .ts files contained in `src`. Otherwise i'll get compile errors. So when they compile, the imports will still point to the source files.

Any sugestions on how to get either typescript or gulp to resolve the paths to the right locations?

Comment: How about keeping your directory structure the same by compiling `src/{lib,test}` to `dist/{lib,test}`? Otherwise, if they're completely independent compile steps then think of them as different projects and consider including a `.d.ts` with the entry point for `lib`

Comment: I went with testing my code in typescript instead. Seemed simpler to just use ts-node.